# Getting SKUs into WCMp Vendor Emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello and thanks in advance.  My first question here, so apologies if it's not 100%.  Also apologies in advance for the massive question - I wanted to include everything I've found and tried.

I'm using [WooCommerce Marketplace (WCMp)](https://wc-marketplace.com/) plugin for vendor management.

When a customer places an order, WMCp fires a New Order email off to the product vendor, and WooCommerce fires an email to the website admin (myself).  As it stands, the email I receive contains the product SKU, however the email that the vendor receives does not.

From what I can see, in the [WooCommerce email template](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-order-items.php), the SKU is displayed through:

```
if ( $show_sku && $sku ) {
echo wp_kses_post( ' (#' . $sku . ')' );
}
```

and $sku is defined further up with:

```
foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
$product       = $item->get_product();
$sku           = '';
$purchase_note = '';
$image         = '';
if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
    continue;
}
if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
    $sku           = $product->get_sku();
    $purchase_note = $product->get_purchase_note();
    $image         = $product->get_image( $image_size );
}
```

In the [WCMp New Order email template](https://github.com/dualcube/dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor/blob/master/templates/emails/vendor-new-order.php), the email contents are called through the vendor_order_item_table function, which is defined [here](https://github.com/dualcube/dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor/blob/master/classes/class-wcmp-vendor-details.php).  Below is the code that I've tried to add in (between line 517 and 518):

```
foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
$product       = $item->get_product();
$sku           = '';
}
if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
    $sku           = $product->get_sku();
}
if ( $show_sku && $sku ) {
echo wp_kses_post( ' (#' . $sku . ')' );
```

I know I'm missing a curly brace at the end - if I add that in, I get an HTTP 500 error.  I've tried commenting out the `if ( $show_sku && $sku ) {` to get around the condition for displaying the echo, but that also generates an HTTP 500 error.

I've tried reaching out to the plugin author, and have spent more than a few days Googling without much luck.

Again, thanks for any help.

*Edit*
I've found the below snippet from [SellWithWP.com](https://www.sellwithwp.com/show-skus-or-photos-in-woocommerce-emails/):

```
function sww_add_sku_to_wc_emails( $args ) {
$args['show_sku'] = true;
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'sww_add_sku_to_wc_emails' );
```

Unfortunately that only adds the SKUs to WooCommerce generated emails (ie, the customer facing email), and not the Vendor New Order email.

Comment: For anyone else looking for this, the plugin author has advised that this is now a planned feature and will be added to their github "soon". [link to forum](https://wc-marketplace.com/support-forum/topic/vendor-new-order-emails-missing-information/#post-43544)

Comment: Another update, version 3.1.6 of the plugin has added the hooks:
`do_action('wcmp_after_vendor_order_table_header', $order, $vendor->term_id);`
and:
`do_action('wcmp_after_vendor_order_item_table', $item, $order, $vendor_id, $is_ship);`
I'm still at a loss as to how to get these to work though.  I get that I make an `add_action( 'wcmp_after_vendor_order_item_table' , 'new_function_that_i_have_to_define_myself' );`, but I have no idea what PHP to use to actually get the SKU codes in there.  I'd really appreciate any guidance at all here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for an answer to this, here's how I got it working:

```
add_action('wcmp_after_vendor_order_item_table', 'add_sku_to_vendor_email', 10, 4);
function add_sku_to_vendor_email($item, $order, $vendor_id, $is_ship) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
        $wcmp_product_sku = $product->get_sku();
        echo wp_kses_post( ' (#' . $wcmp_product_sku . ')' );
}
```

...added into functions.php, or as a snippet.

This puts the SKU below the cost price on each line - not exactly what I was looking for, but good enough (given how much time I sunk into it).